# Add custom field in exposed form in view

Tags: views

I have a view with exposed form. I want to add some **custom select field** in this exposed form. I have tried with **hook_form_alter()** but the field is rendered in form **submit** button wrapper which is strange. How can I add a custom field to another one filters ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the field as a widget by messing with the `#info` part of the form in `hook_form_alter` - it's not very elegant but hey.

```
$form['text_search'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => t('Or start typing here to find your competition.'),
  '#default_value' => '',
);
// Create widget from new form item.
$new_form_info = array(
  'filter-text_search' => array('value' => 'text_search'),
);
// Put new widget definition at top, so widget will appear
// first (change order to change to desired position).
$form['#info'] = $new_form_info += $form['#info'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is correct, but not clear
You need to do so

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hayly_helper_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $query = Drupal::request()->query;
  $parent_category = $query->get('parent');
  
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $form['parent'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#title' => t('Parent'),
      '#default_value' => $parent_category ?? '',
    ];

    __hayly_insert_field_to_exposed_form($form, 'filter-parent', $parent_category, 0);
  }
}

function __hayly_insert_field_to_exposed_form(&$form, $field_key, $value, $insert_index) {
  // this value determines the position of the new element.
  $element_to_insert = array();
  $element_to_insert[$field_key] = array(
    'value' => $value,
  );

  $form_info_top = array_slice($form['#info'], 0, $insert_index);
  $form_info_bottom = array_slice($form['#info'], $insert_index);
  $new_form_info = $form_info_top + $element_to_insert + $form_info_bottom;
  $form['#info'] = $new_form_info;
}
```

If you have custom exposed filter twig - **don't forget** to print your new field in your `views-exposed-form.html.twig` `{{ form.parent }}`
Also you can read [**this answer**](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/893392) for more info